# Column names that contain NAs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a large data frame that contains 900 variables per row. I am trying to write a function that gives me the name of each column that contains a NA for each row.

For example:

```
x-> 

               mpg  cyl disp hp draw wt
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 NA   2.62
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  NA  110 3.90 NA 
Datsun 710    22.8   4  NA  93  NA   NA
```

I would like a function to return:

```
Mazda RX4:   "draw"
Mazda RX4 Wag: "disp", "wt"
Datsun 710: "disp","draw","wt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `apply` by row to select from `colnames(x)`. Probably going to get a list since the result is ragged.

```
 apply(x, 1, function(x2) colnames(x)[ is.na(x2) ] )
$`Mazda RX4`
[1] "draw"

$`Mazda RX4 Wag`
[1] "disp" "wt"  

$`Datsun 710`
[1] "disp" "draw" "wt"
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I'm new with R and really appreciate the help. My only question is what will x2 be defined as?

Comment: `x2` is a temporary value that will change as `apply` moves from row to row, and after the function is done, then `x2` will be available to be garbage collected. Technically in the terms that describe R's syntax it is is a formal argument to an anonymous function.